# image resolution on website, when resize

Tags: image, web, resize, resolution, photoshop

I created this image with photoshop 4500x2646px 72dpi, I want to show my picture in a div of 700x412px.

- 1 resize with photoshop, 700x412px 72dpi quality 12 (max) -> 216Kb and the quality (according to my scale) on my site is 8 (from 0 to 10).
- 2 resize with photoshop, 1400x824px 72dpi quality 12 (max) -> 683Kb and the quality (according to my scale) on my site is 10 (from 0 to 10).

Why if the browser resize an original image of **1400px to 700px** the quality of the pictures are better than use a pictures resize by photoshop ?

The resize method of a browser is better the photoshop ?

I'm using a full hd screen.

Thanks

Comment: No it isnt better. You also dont save any traffic if you let the browser resize. And you definitely want to save traffic.

Comment: When you use big-resolution image on the lower screen or div (ie: 700x700px image in the div with sizes 350x350px), then you get better quality - that's also how retina works.

Comment: This question has no relation to programming since there's also no code to support it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It can be related to html, as they are scaling through a div. But they should remove the php and css tags.

Comment: I removed the php, html and css tags from your question. Up until that you can show relevance to the question, you should not use those tags if there's no code to support it.

Answer (score 1):

If you resize a 4500x2646px image with html/css in a Browser, it will still have to download the full image and use bandwidth. It's not like having a server program resize and save a new image like a thumbnail.

It also may depend on what method the specific Browser is using to resample the image, nearest-neighbor or bicubic.

Take a look at the different options in Photoshop for resizing/resampling. And Flatten the image first so that the edges don't blur, then Save As JPEG. But do not save over your PSD as flattened or you won't get your layers back.

[image: Photoshop Image Resize]

There are more quality options if you choose Save for Web.

[image: Photoshop Save for Web]

And if the image is still not crisp enough, I put a Smart Sharpen Filter of 15%, 1.0px Radius.

Comment: The question has no code to support it and isn't related to programming. They tagged as php, html, css but no code. I can't see how your answer will help solve this. Sure hoping you didn't do all that for nothing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see, I thought they had also tagged it in photoshop. If I understand correctly, they say the browser is doing better scaling than photoshop, but I'd have to see it myself.

Comment: I removed those tags and left them a comment under the question. They can add them back in "after" they've added relevant code.